# Why is <c:forEach> on an Enum is empty under Glassfish4 (5 beta)?

Tags: jsp, glassfish, jstl

I want to put the constants of an Enum into an html dropdown but it is not being generated under glassfish.

I tried the same example under tomcat 8 and it is working fine.
I verified that JSTL is working by having a test `c:cout`.  I have determined that the EL is not being evaluated.  I do not have `web.xml`

What could be the problem?

Enum Code:

```
public enum ColorEnum {Red, Green, Blue}
```

JSP code fragment

```
<select name="color">
    <c:forEach var="element" items="${ColorEnum.values()}">
        <option value="${element}">${element}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The generated html under glassfish is:

```
<select name="color">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround to the problem is to set the expression as a scope attribute in the servlet, and then change `items="${ColorEnum.values()}"` to `items="${colors}"`.

Does anyone have a better solution?